# Past + Present Sentence

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, present-tense

Once I read a rule on the internet that if the second part of a sentence is a universal truth then don't change it to past.

**For example: My teacher told me that the sun rises from the east.**

But I'm not sure about the following examples whether it's right or wrong. Both sentences have different meaning to me

**1: She told me yesterday that she was pregnant.**

**2: She told me yesterday that she's pregnant.**

In the first example it sounds like she has already given birth to a baby and she's no longer pregnant.

In the second example it sounds like she still has some time to deliver a baby.

Am I right?
And sorry if it sounds silly to you.

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford if both means the same then what if someone tells me that she was pregnant and I want to tell it to my friend and I say he told me that she was pregnant. Would it mean the same that she's still pregnant?

Comment: So long as she still *is* pregnant, then the choice is yours. If you think there's the possibility of misinterpretation with the use of *was*, then use *is*. (It's highly unlikely that she gave birth in the last 24 hours—unless, for example, her baby was due anytime and you're talking to somebody from a hospital.) Context determines the meaning.

Comment: @JasonBassford ah ok and thanks for the explanation :)